# fetch should not be in the action || reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

1. I'm doing it right if I put the `fetch` in the `componentDidMount ()`? It is folly to put the `fetch` into the action or reducer?
2. Why this {this.props.data.name} does not work without setting of standard parameters for data in reducer? Without this `(state = {data: { }}, action)`?!

### Reducer

```
const reducer = (state = {
  data: {

  }
}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'EXPERIMENT':
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.data
      }
      break
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default reducer
```

### Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class Persistent extends Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    fetch('https://api.github.com/users/reactjs').then((response) => {
      response.json().then((json) => {
        this.props.dispatch({
          type: 'EXPERIMENT',
          data: json
        })
      })
    })
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <ol>
          <li>{this.props.data.name}</li>
          <li>{this.props.data.url}</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(
  (state) => {
    return {
      data: state.data
    }
  }
)(Persistent)
```

Comment: It is fine to put it in an action creator.

Comment: Use redux-thunk middleware. It allows action creators to return functions instead of action objects. The functions are chained to do a final dispatch of an action object.

Comment: @vijayst I guess you can put this as an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) middleware. It allows action creators to return functions instead of action objects. The functions are chained to do a final dispatch of an action object.

While creating the store, include the middleware as follows:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import RootReducer from '../reducers/rootReducer';

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();

export function configureStore(initialState) {
  return createStore(
    RootReducer,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(
      thunkMiddleware,
      loggerMiddleware
    ));
}
```

An example of an action creator which uses the thunk middleware:

```
getCards(email, token) {
    return (dispatch, getStore) => {
      dispatch(CardActions.getCardsRequest(email));
      fetch(apiUrls.getCardsUrl + email, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Api-Key': token,
        },
      })
      .then(response => {
        return response.json().then(responseJson => {
          return dispatch(CardActions.getCardsResponse(responseJson.postcards, response.status));
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      });
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. One of key constraint of redux is that reducers have to be pure functions. What it means is that it cannot have side-effects like fetching data. So in short fetch cannot go into reducer.
2. reducer is a function and `(state = {data: { }}, action)` are parameters to reducer function with the part `{data: { }}` being the default value for the state. Your code uses es2015 arrow functions syntax which is equivalent of plain old js:

   ```
   function reducer(state = {data: { }}, action) {
     switch (action.type) {
       case 'EXPERIMENT':
         return {
           ...state,
           data: action.data
         }
         break
       default:
         return state
     }
   }
   ```

It won't work without setting default parameters because store won't have necessary objects.